# Firebase Phone Auth on Android

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have implemented the Firebase email and Google Signin correctly and it works fine on both iOS and Android.
Then I've tried to implement the Over the Phone Auth and first it doesn't work on iPhone but then I did some research and it seems I had to upload some APNs and finally I set it up correctly and now it works on iPhone, but when I try to send SMS to Android it doesn't receive it but sends me the message that indicates the code was sent just like on iPhone.

The strangest thing is if I put the iPhone's mobile number it gets the SMS code. So I wonder if I have to enable some type of Push notifications on Android like I did on iPhone or if I have to set up some real developer account, cause right now I don't have the Google's one or there's is something else I'm missing.

Can anyone help me with this, please?

The auth method I'm using is the one of the Flutter example:

```
class _PhoneSignInSection extends StatefulWidget {
  _PhoneSignInSection(this._scaffold);

  final ScaffoldState _scaffold;
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _PhoneSignInSectionState();
}

class _PhoneSignInSectionState extends State<_PhoneSignInSection> {
  final TextEditingController _phoneNumberController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _smsController = TextEditingController();

  String _message = '';
  String _verificationId;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: const Text('Test sign in with phone number'),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: _phoneNumberController,
          decoration:
              InputDecoration(labelText: 'Phone number (+x xxx-xxx-xxxx)'),
          validator: (String value) {
            if (value.isEmpty) {
              return 'Phone number (+x xxx-xxx-xxxx)';
            }
            return null;
          },
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              _verifyPhoneNumber();
            },
            child: const Text('Verify phone number'),
          ),
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: _smsController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Verification code'),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              _signInWithPhoneNumber();
            },
            child: const Text('Sign in with phone number'),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: Text(
            _message,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  // Example code of how to verify phone number
  void _verifyPhoneNumber() async {
    setState(() {
      _message = '';
    });
    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
        (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
      _auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
      setState(() {
        _message = 'Received phone auth credential: $phoneAuthCredential';
      });
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
        (AuthException authException) {
      setState(() {
        _message =
            'Phone number verification failed. Code: ${authException.code}. Message: ${authException.message}';
      });
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
        (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
      widget._scaffold.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content:
            const Text('Please check your phone for the verification code.'),
      ));

      _verificationId = verificationId;
    };

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
        (String verificationId) {
      _verificationId = verificationId;
    };

    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: _phoneNumberController.text,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
  }

  // Example code of how to sign in with phone.
  void _signInWithPhoneNumber() async {
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: _verificationId,
      smsCode: _smsController.text,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user =
        (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential));
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
    setState(() {
      if (user != null) {
        _message = 'Successfully signed in, uid: ' + user.uid;
      } else {
        _message = 'Sign in failed';
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And my App level build.gradle have this dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

As the guide says:

> Add the dependency for the Firebase Authentication Android library to
>   your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually app/build.gradle):
>   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'

And of course I have  `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in the same build.gradle

EDIT: When it test with whitelisted phone numbers, I'm successfully signing in on Android.

Comment: In firebase phone authentication you can setup some test numbers, have you tried with those numbers. They don't send SMS for those numbers, you would enter predefined verification code. Just to narrow down the problem

Comment: Hi, Chenna yes it works fine when I test with whitelisted numbers. I'll edit my question to include this one too. Goog point!

Comment: To understand the problem, you have two different phone numbers one in iPhone and another one Android device. You don't have any problem when you give iPhone phone number (have you tried this from both the Android and iPhone apps),  do you receive SMS when you give iOS Phone number on Android App?

Comment: Can you also change `_auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
      setState(() {
        _message = 'Received phone auth credential: $phoneAuthCredential';
      })` to `_auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).then((u) {setState(){...}});`

Comment: When I send it from Android app to iPhone number I receive the code. When send it from the iPhone to the iPhone it receives it too. When I send it from the iPhone app to Android number it didn't receive it and when send it from Android app to Android number it doesn't receive it neither.

Comment: hmm just received this message: "Code cuota exceeded. We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later." I'ts the first time I receive this one. It seems Firebase have blocked the device, but not sure about the phone number. I'll google it to see what I may do about it.

Comment: So it doesn't sound like problem with your App. It might be problem with your Android Mobile number. Usually this happens for roaming numbers (I ran into this problem). It might be a good idea to try with third number to be sure. Or if easier, just swap the sims and try.

Comment: Yes, they block it if you continuosly request. It would be unblocked after sometime (don't remember how long)

Comment: May be i'll swap it later. It's a good idea! Will stay in touch.

Comment: @ChennaReddy I've tried third number and it works like a charm, so if you post it like answer I'll accept it. The number I had previously is some SIM my operator gave me like a gift, they don't charge me for use it but has some limitations and despite receiving SMS is not one of those it seems Google don't like it. So please when you answer include this explainer too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phone number in iPhone is receiving SMS successfully from both Android and iOS Apps.
Phone number in Android is not receiving in any SMS from either Android or iOS App.

So the problem is not really with the App but with Phone Number/SIM in Android phone. *This can happen if the Phone is in roadming or if there are any restrictions no the Phone numbers, then Firebase might not send SMS*. Apparantly this is what happening. To make sure this is the problem, better to test with another phone Number. If its working with the new phone number, we can conclude its problem with a particular Phone number but not with your phone.

You might want to re-write following code (in those lines):

```
_auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
setState(() {
  _message = 'Received phone auth credential: $phoneAuthCredential';
});
```

to

```
_auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)
.then((user) {setState(){
  _message = 'Received phone auth credential: $phoneAuthCredential';
}})
.catchError((error) {
  _message = 'Something went wrong: $error';
});
```

So that you are sure making sure `_auth.signInWithCredential` is successful before informing user.